# How do I embed the entire Excel workbook in an MS Word 2010 document?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, embedding

In Office 2007, I could embed the entire Excel workbook into an MS Word document.  The Word page would show an icon for the Excel file.  It did not display any of the contents of the workbook on the Word page.  When the reader double-clicked on the icon, the Excel file would open like any other Excel file showing all cells and worksheets.  The user can modify the Excel contents and save the workbook as a separate file from the Word file.

Is there a way to place the entire Excel file into a Word 2010 document without displaying any of the cell contents on the Word page?

Answer (score 7):

Sorry this was not answered sooner. If you still need to know how to do this, here is what I do.

In Word, select the *Insert* ribbon, choose *Object*. On the Object window (screen shot below), select the *Create From File* tab. Browse to find the file you want to imbed. Then check the box for *Display As Icon*. Click OK and it will place an in on your page.

[image]